# Is there a way to subscribe to Redis Streams similar to Redis pub/sub?

Tags: redis, architecture, daemon, system-design, redis-streams

I am building a data pipeline that reads the MySQL binlogs in realtime using [Maxwell Daemon](http://maxwells-daemon.io) and Maxwell Daemon pushes the data to Redis streams. I've built a client that consumes the data from Redis streams processes it. Currently, I'm polling the **XREAD** using an infinite loop with a sleep time of few milliseconds to consume the data from the stream, but I find this to be an inefficient solution.

I was searching for a way where I can somehow subscribe to the Redis stream and get notified whenever new entries are added to the stream and came across [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1155) GitHub issue where they talk about using the Redis pub/sub along with streams to achieve this functionality.

Is there a more efficient way of architecting this system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `BLOCK` argument of `XREAD` and you'll have same "efficiency".

Documentation: https://redis.io/commands/xread and https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro#listening-for-new-items-with-xread

Comment: Thanks, Itamar Haber! I'll look into `XREAD` with `BLOCK`. Just wanted to know one more thing if it's good to use in production?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go in production

Comment: @ItamarHaber, is there any way redis can push (not pull) data to consumer (subscriber) using streams?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question - Redis does push the data to clients that establish a connection and consume (subscribe) the data.